# how to replace a value in a division for every 5 seconds in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace a value in a `div` with id `show_num_val` with new value for every 5 seconds. For that I have written the following.

```
<div id="show_num_val"> 0 </div>
```

In the script:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {      
  for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    showThis(i);
  }      
});

function showThis(x) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#show_num_val').html(x);
  }, 5000);
 }
</script>
```

But I am getting the last value i.e `20` only in the `show_num_val` div.
can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**setInterval()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) if you want repetitive execution.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FmSxM/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    x = 1;
    inverval = setInterval(function() {
                $('#show_num_val').html(x++);
                if(x == 21)
                     clearInterval(inverval);
               }, 2000);​

});
```

Comment: You are welcome, I have updated my answer to stop it after 20 iterations

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 0;
T = setInterval(function() {
  if (x == 20) clearInterval(T);
  $('#show_num_val').html(x); 
  x++;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please explain bit about the code written. What it does/return or else?? That would help all....

Answer (score 0):

See it working http://jsbin.com/ajekeq/2/watch

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {      
    for(i=1; i<20; i++){
      showThis(i, 5000 * i));
    }      
  });

  function showThis(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#show_num_val').html(x);
    }, y);
   }
  </script>
```

The reason why your code was not working because all the timers were getting over at the same time. I would have liked to use setInterval though as we are starting 20 timers at the same time. Another model is to start next timer in the setTimeout call till you are done.